# Android: Do not display the scrollbar of ListView when ListView displays

Tags: android, listview, scrollbar

I have a ListView, when this ListView displays, its scrollbar also displays and fades out later, I want scroolbar only displays when scrolling, how to do?

Comment: HI, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Could you show what you've done to try and make the scrollbar only display when scrolling so far?  It'd be appreciated, as it shows the community that you've given some effort to the question and also allows us to answer your question more quickly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For this use the below property for listview in xml file

```
android:scrollbars="none"
```

and in java file us ethe following code to enable scrollbars

```
lv.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                lv.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
            }
        });
```

Comment: HI, thank you for the response. but it does not work, setScrollbarFadingEnabled only for scrollbar fading, not for enabling scrollbar, but it's the right direction, not sure why Google does this annoying feature for ListView.